# What's with all the PHP hate?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, new-users, question-quality

**Somebody else has to have noticed that questions that get hit by the nuclear downvote warhead are usually related, whether directly or peripherally, to PHP.**

I'd assert also that part of this downvote storm happens because PHP is often people's first language, and is often self-taught in early stages.  Furthermore, I'm **certain** that there is a better way to deal with such questions than downvoting them into oblivion and leaving unpleasant, sarcastic comments.

The best way I can think of to deal with questions like this would be to immediately recognize that you're dealing with a question with a known fundamental flaw: the writer's broadly incomplete knowledge of the language, and of programming in general.  You might be thinking that that statement is a little harsh, but anecdotally, I started using PHP when I was about 14. If I'd known SO had existed then, I'd probably have earned myself a posting ban within less than a week with all of the low quality crap I'd have posted.  PHP was my second language, and I was using it long before I had any sort of structured programming education.  I'd imagine that a significant portion of early PHP users, such like those who ask questions like those currently being discussed, are in a similar situation.

So anyway.  Step one is to read the question, and search not only for the problem, which will likely be obvious, but also for *The Problem* (the underlying misconception or lack of knowledge that led to the asking of the flawed question) which will be hidden between the lines.  The second would be to address both problems, with special emphasis on *The Problem*.  A good way to do this might be to keep tried, tested, and well-informed PHP tutorials on hand, as well as recommendations about good style and good practice.

Remember that new developers are like children: the things that influence their early style will create habits that will be very hard to break later; it's imperative, for their future as developers, that they be guided towards good practices that promote structured development and maintainability, as well as readability and safety and testability and a host of other things, and that a lack of guidance will have a similarly destructive effect on their ability to adapt to better practices later.

For what it's worth, it helps to remember that you were all the same way once; guideless and directionless, adrift in a sea of bad practice and sloppy code that if you went back now and tried to read it, it would make you cry blood.  I still occasionally run into code I wrote back then and man, it's horrid.

Things to come away from this question include:

- Every time you downvote a question without explaining why, god teaches another 14 year old that PHP exists but doesn't explain how to use it
- Constructive criticism is good
- People can learn if you teach them, even those with really dumb questions
- You were a noob once too

## TL;DR

Excessive hostility during larval stage maims and deforms developers, but proper care cultivates talented ones who don't write code that makes people want to vomit.

## Assertions

1. When I see a dumb question, even if I don't downvote it, I usually comment on it, trying to say something constructive that might explain what's missing or why other people are downvoting.  I think everyone should explain themselves if they downvote something, it makes correcting the problem much easier.  You can only please the masses if you know what they want.
2. When you identify a question asked by a fledgling programmer with a flawed understanding of a language, you should put a little effort into correcting their understanding.  It can make a big difference in their output.
3. Those who can, if you see such a question, consider searching for a duplicate and voting to close, rather than downvoting it.  If applied frequently, this method will teach users to search for their question before they ask it, especially if you add a comment like "You should search for your question before posting it because chances are it's already been asked."

## Questions

1. How do you deal with questions that fit this description?
2. Do you enjoy downvoting bad questions?  I sort of do (but I make sure to explain why). Be honest.
3. Since PHP seems to specifically exhibit this issue more than other topics, what are some objectively good PHP learners' aids; tutorials, practice guides, examples, etc?

## Examples

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393798/input-text-clickable [CAOP, prose clearly indicates young developer]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393873/how-to-add-a-check-username-and-password [CAOP, foreign developer]
- [Convert plain-text link to HyperLink in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394500/convert-plain-text-link-to-hyperlink-in-php) [open, simple issue, crappy answer, poor explanation of downvotes in comments]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394289/trouble-understanding-php-template-concepts-not-engine-specific [CAOP, "first web app", new developer]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391980/simple-instagram-impossible [CAOP, not a horrible question, no downvote explanation, presumably simple solution]

CAOP stands for "closed as of posting", i.e. the question was open when I included a link to it, and has since been closed.

## Evidence

The accuracy of my claims of bias has been questioned.  Rudimentary statistics, considering ONLY THE FIRST PAGE of each tag (statistics over wider periods of time may vary)

```
NDQ: Number of Downvoted Questions
RDUQ: Ratio of Downvoted to Upvoted Questions (treats each question as 1)
TD: Total Downvotes (on all downvoted question)

Tag:            NDQ:    RDUQ:   TD:     Notes:
PHP             7       3.5     25      subject in question. many downvoted questions.
Python          2       0.2     4       random language tag. opposite trend.
multithreading  4       0.5     22      random niche tag. a few really bad questions.
mysql           8       1.0     13      related tag.  5 of 8 downvoted are also tagged PHP
```

Comment: It might be important to recognize that PHP is not exactly a well-liked language, and that "targeting PHP devs early" might help change it into something better in the long run.

Comment: Can you give some examples of questions like this?

Comment: Do you have any examples you can point to?

Comment: I bet many of these downvotes come from [the infamous PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/11/php) =)

Comment: I'm actually out scraping for them right now.  The most common constructive comment is to post anything they've tried, but usually, its not recognized that the developer is probably a new one.  You can find a few yourself by visiting the php tag and searching for downvoted questions.  I don't see any on p1 of the unanswered list right now, but I'm asking because I saw one earlier, and see them on a daily basis.  Also, examples will not stay relevant for long because they get closed and removed frequently.

Comment: Everyone was a new programmer. But not everyone demands all the code to be delivered to them on a plate hidden behind a scrag bush

Comment: Have you got any statistics to compare relative down-voting behaviour across tags? I assure you I down-vote bad questions regardless of tag, I am non-discriminatory like that.

Comment: This question makes a __lot__ of assumptions. I think you'll have to justify some of them before we can have a constructive discussion.

Comment: Also, your comment broke your list numbering. Not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: Have you considered that PHP is pretty high on the list due to the relative competence of the questions/answers provided rather than a general hate of PHP. All languages have their -10+ voted questions. However, if the average quality of an q/a then can't you expect more downvotes; for whatever reason.

Comment: You sure picked five insanely hard examples to defend...good on you for trying to stick up for them, but I doubt you'll get traction with this question if you don't find better examples.

Comment: Aaaand 4 of the 5 questions as examples are now closed.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: what a shock.  I guess I'll have to search for others.  Even the instagram one, which I'm sure would have at least been answered if it had been asked about python or C#.  My point wasn't that these were great questions that didn't deserve criticism.  It was that the kind of criticism they got doesn't help at all.

Comment: Your argument and rationale don't seem to apply strictly to PHP. There's dumb questions in every language on SO. From what I can tell the only reason you mentioned PHP is because of your 3rd question. Are there any metrics to show that PHP gets more downvotes disproportionate to its popularity?

Comment: @MikeB: I added some rudimentary metrics.  It's important to note that I counted them from before I posted them as examples, which caused a further rain of downvotes.

Comment: @Wug I appreciate the metrics and I didn't mean to come off as glib. Your intentions are very noble. However your sampling only includes 2 of the top 6 most-popular tags.

Comment: @PopularDemand I've justified some of my assumptions, using a 3 second random sample.  If you want more than that you'll have to wait for me to get out of work.

Comment: @MikeB: as it turns out, I suspect that javascript suffers from a similar pattern (though I haven't checked it). If you want, I'll post some much more detailed metrics later, covering dozens of tags and hundreds or thousands of questions.  I'll make sure to ask a question about how to parse numbers our of JSON using a regex using javascript generated by php so I can write my scraper. :)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I bet (/ know) it isn't. And such a claim is rather a bit ridiculous imho.

Comment: ...Because PHP.

Comment: @Wug You could call it the cynicism metric broken down by tag :p

Comment: I was absolutely kidding, @PeeHaa.  I hoped that the goofy smiling emoticon would make that clear, but I suppose not.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I was told so later. Sarcasm sucks on the internet :D Hope you don't mind I did downvote all your questions before your explanation :P

Comment: @PeeHaa Ooooh, I'm telling!

Comment: @Wug I appreciate the update. Numbers are always nice. But I was more concerned with the motivation behind the numbers. How do we know that `[php]` has a higher percentage of newbie programmers than other tags (as opposed to good programmers who aren't good at using English, or veterans who just never got very good at programming)? How do we know that downvoters are targeting `[php]` questions because of their `[php]`-ness? __If__ a tag actually attracts lots of low-quality questions for some reason, then it _should_ attract lots of downvotes.

Comment: @PopularDemand: harder to address.  If I can, I'll whip up something that checks things such as join dates of users who ask questions, though this is a little trickier to farm useful information from.  However, the point is that for some reason, there is either a bias against PHP, or a significant setback with PHP developers that's showing up via trends in the ultimate empirical measure of question quality (downvotes).  I'm not saying the questions are good and should be praised, just that downvote sniping apparently isn't working.

Comment: Gotcha. There seem to be (at least) three distinct sub-questions here: "Is there a bias against PHP?"; "Should there be a bias against PHP?"; and "What can we do about PHP?" On top of all that, determining whether downvoting is working depends on the desired outcome of the downvoting. Are we trying to maximize overall, worldwide average code quality? Keep old members happy? Keep new members happy? Anyways, thanks again for addressing this issue in a civil, non-ranty way.

Comment: @PopularDemand: I haven't touched PHP in years, and I hate the language. I can't stand using it now. I've worked my fair share of atrocities in it in the past.  Maybe I'd hate it less if it had some educational structure around it, in the way that java does.  I'm not a huge fan of java either, I hate parts of it too (I'm pretty sure everyone hates something about every language), but I respect the fact that it's well taught, and structured learning of a language can bring you a long way to writing "good" code with it, even if you don't like it.

Comment: I've also thought about posting a question like this about 3 or 4 separate times, and lost interest halfway through, over the past few months.

Comment: @Wug PHP has an ingrained culture of developers who are not willing to put any effort in. Some of these are new developers asking dumb questions in the same way that everyone did *occasionally*, but far more of them are repeat/serial offenders. You can tell the (dare I say it?) *real* developers who show up in the PHP tag from a mile off. They ask questions with code samples. They post actual error messages. They use descriptive question titles. They don't ask you to spoon feed them. They *read the answers properly* before saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't disagree with you on this, I think the PHP community is too snarky, sarcastic and generally unfriendly. But it is not totally baseless - it has turned into a vicious circle.

Comment: @DaveRandom: This post isn't about those people who ask those questions, they're just fine for the most part. It specifically addresses what I, personally, think should change about how we deal with the other ones.  I'm trying to break the vicious cycle.

Comment: I like how someone went into my SO answers 52 minutes ago and randomly downvoted ones they didn't like. Not enough to be serial downvoting, but still obviously correlated to checking my profile, reviewing all of my answers, and downvoting some of them.  They were 3 months old, the timing is just too perfect.

Comment: @Wug ...but my (not very well expressed) point is that those people, for the most part, get what they deserve. From my observations as someone who roams the purple hills of the PHP tag, brand new users who ask bad questions get "Welcome to SO, please read the FAQ/how to ask pages" comments and the like, and do not get the instant influx of down/close votes. Repeat offenders, however, do not get the same treatment. And those people don't learn, either - they inevitably get banned from asking questions and wind up in PHP chat, asking the same poorly researched RTFM questions.

Comment: @Wug flag one of your posts and explain you suspect serial downvoting and I'm sure it will get reversed.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I lost 4 reputation.  I don't care that much about it.

Comment: "I'd probably have earned myself a posting ban within less than a week with all of the low quality crap I'd have posted" - and therein lies the problem.

Comment: @Kev: but wherein lies the solution?

Comment: We already have one - a self moderating community that closes and deletes this crap. This problem isn't specific to PHP, every popular tag has its fair share of sewage flowing down the river - go check out the IOS and Android tags, the eye watering stench that the experienced regulars have to put up with there can be mind bending. Also is it fair that users who have well researched questions that need answers should be drowned out by questions from other users who can't be arsed learning how to communicate?

Comment: Correlation is not causation. Have you considered that it's equally likely that bad questions are consistently asked by new-to-PHP developers? It's an incredibly popular language with virtually no barrier to entry.

Comment: @Kev: maybe I'm asking the question, "how do we arse them to do things."

Comment: I would downvote this a second time for your "evidence" if I could. Your statistics are laughably small and they do not support your claim.

Comment: It's a shame that this question has been closed.

Comment: `... questions that get hit by the nuclear downvote warhead are usually related, whether directly or peripherally, to PHP`: So true. Look at the vote count for this question: **it is related to PHP**...

Comment: why this is closed

Answer (score 25):

To the extent that PHP gets more downvotes than other tags, I think it can be easily explained by the proportion of inexperienced users asking bad questions, most of which could have been answered by a quick search.

The default state of public internet sites is useless garbage. Sites that *aren't* garbage are constantly trying to go *back* to being garbage. They **want** to be garbage, the law of internet gravity pulls them towards it: it's their natural resting state. Countering this downward force and preventing sites from becoming garbage requires the constant exertion of moderator energy (`M`) along an opposing vector. If we start making exceptions to the site's standards, it's only a matter of time (and not that much time) before the weight (`W=N+T+S`) of the noobs, trolls, and spammers brings it down.

If the site is going to keep the experts who provide the answers interested it must constantly work to maintain some quality standards. If some people can't handle negative feedback, that's their problem. They will not be missed.

[image: At least I have chicken]

QED, no sympathy for bad questions.

Comment: what the f*ck am I reading lol *edit* also, the post isn't about surrendering and becoming garbage. It's about long run working to make the PHP development community not as much of a steaming heap as it currently is.  Also +1 for the very informative diagram.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive theoretical explanation of the Internet that I have ever read, and I predict it will one day be taught in classrooms. In the interest of scientific clarity, however, you should explain in more detail what the brown smeared segment in your illustraion represents.

Answer (score 17):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with this post, but you seem to think people that are following the [php] tag are more willing to downvote questions. Or you notice that [php] questions often get lots of downvotes.

Well as a follower of the [php] tag (among other tags) I can tell you the PHP tag produces just so many *crap*. And if a question is crap I really don't mind to downvote it without any remorse. I don't think I get a particular good feeling about downvoting often, it's the opposite. It makes me a little sad because of the fact there is so much crap that deserves a downvote.

> Excessive hostility during larval stage maims and deforms developers, but proper care cultivates talented ones who don't write code that makes people want to vomit.

A downvote is not an action of hostility. It is an action of housekeeping / quality assurance.

> When I see a dumb question, even if I don't downvote it, I usually comment on it,

Although I do agree with you that a comment is the nice thing to do, but you have to keep some things in mind:

- SO has chosen to NOT make this mandatory. I.e. any user may or may not add a comment when downvoting. This is the way SO wants it to be. You may agree or not, but the fact is: Comments are not mandatory for downvotes period.
- Even doing "the right thing" and comment when you downvote. OP still wouldn't like it in some cases and goes on a downvoting spree to "get back". Even when both the comment and the downvote are justified
- Some downvotes should be clear to OP without any explanation if they only would have taken the time to: Read the faq, read the How to ask page or plain simple common sense.

> When you identify a question asked by a fledgling programmer with a flawed understanding of a language, you should put a little effort into correcting their understanding.

I'm all for correcting of understanding of a language. That is if the misunderstanding is not something OP could have simply found out by reading into some documentation him/herself. Or when OP doesn't just give some set of requirements and yell `canihaztehcodez`.

> Those who can, if you see such a question, consider searching for a duplicate and voting to close,

100% agree. When there are dupes close vote as dupe. However when there are 10.000 exact dupes already to be easily found on SO I say downvote and close as dupe. And after it is closed delete it. If there are already 1000s dupes it shows a lack of research of OP (which imho deserves a downvote).

So now to your questions:

> How do you deal with questions that fit this description?

Downvote when they deserve it without even blinking with my eyes (yes I'm an ice-cold downvoter) :) And close vote if it cannot be salvaged. Leave a comment if OP could fix it and add it to my list to check later for improvement.

> Do you enjoy downvoting bad questions? I sort of do (but I make sure to explain why). Be honest.

No it makes my a sad sad panda.

> Since PHP seems to specifically exhibit this issue more than other topics

PHP is a easy language to start in "coding". Hence everybody just starts doing stuff without reading any documentation, without doing any research. Besides this fact there will always be lots of people trying it out (e.g. new users). And besides this [php] has a nice community who tries to keep it tidy / tries to do housekeeping. Which is a good thing imho. Basically [php] attracts a lot of crap (I think more so than most other tags) and the fact that you see a lot of downvotes makes two things clear:

1. php produces crap
2. the community around the php tag are serious about cleaning op SO

> , what are some objectively good PHP learners' aids; tutorials, practice guides, examples, etc?

There are a lot of terrible tutorials on the web which is a serious problem for PHP. THe ultimate source for PHP is [the official manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) which is maintained by the community and is a **very** good resource on most topics. Also there is another community driven resource here called [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Since you also have a tl;dr:

### TL;DR

Crap questions should get the downvotes they deserve. There is no bias for [php] only for low quality posts.

Comment: Optimally, you'd be 100% correct, but if you were 13, and you asked a question, and it was downvoted to like -6 in 3 minutes and nobody posted anything explaining why, would you see that as hostility?  
This post is calling attention to a problem that seemingly extends far beyond SO (the fact that much of php development is subjectively crap). I'm trying to point out that the way to transform the perpetrators of said crap into something less crappy probably doesn't involve alienating them (intentionally or otherwise) and that if PHP is to be considered not crap, real effort is probably needed.

Comment: If you are 13 you are not allowed to have an account on SO. Even if 13 year olds were allowed to make an account on SO I wouldn't change my habits one single bit. If a question deserves a downvote it gets a downvote. Whether it is from a 13 year old, some php guru or some hot chick. It gets what it deserves. When people ask their first question they have to tick a checkbox stating they have read and understood the "How to ask" page. Which in most situations should prevent spitting out crap in the first place.

Comment: You can post without having an account.

Comment: Either way I just found out you are allowed to signup from 13 years old. MY point still stands. Why would the community not use the tools the have because someone is young? Should we just let the entire community go down the drain because we may hurt somebody's feelings?

Comment: I think your opinion of how to help the community differs from mine.  I understand that downvotes help make a point, but I co-assert that explanation of opinion is a much more concrete way to help.  It's tedious helping newbs like this, but keeping a watchful eye for untrained developers and responding accordingly with General Known Good Advice and/or links to Known Good Resources such as php.net, stackoverflow's PHP chat, or other places talented PHP devs congregate, will help them learn by example.  Nobody said fixing the PHP community would be easy or fun.

Comment: It's ok if you have a different opinion. It's a free country (unless you are from the USA ;) ), but judging on the voting in this thread the community doesn't really agree with your opinion. Again this is also fine. Still a free country (unless from the USA).

Comment: Have you heard about quantum romneyism? :D http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/01/opinion/sunday/a-quantum-theory-of-mitt-romney.html

Comment: @Wug Looking it up now :)

Comment: Just wanted to highlight [this question asked earlier today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146856/155826), which sort of highlights the main reason Stack Exchange doesn't make comments mandatory on downvotes.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow is a question and answer board, not an instructional site to teach people how to program.  It's not that we enjoy downvoting; we are fixing the signal-to-noise ratio for the site.

Comment: Speak for yourself. I *thoroughly enjoy* issuing a well-deserved down vote. :p

Comment: If you want to fix the S/N ratio, use the close button, not the downvote button.

Comment: @Wug Both are tools we have that we can use. May I suggest it's our decision when to use either (or both)? For example, I'm strongly considering down voting this question, but I would not consider voting to close it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Downvotes are different on meta.  I know I'm playing the devils advocate and that this question will be downvoted and I don't care. Someone should do it now and then, its good for you.

Comment: @Wug Actually, my down vote here would be for *exactly* the same reason as on many of those I do on Stack Overflow; lack of proper research.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  Perhaps you mean my brief eyeballed collection of data for 4 or 5 tags?  I'll be updating this with a significantly more in depth set of metrics later tonight, generated from the API via a script.  Or maybe you mean the fact that the questions really are bad?  That's kind of the point of my question. Perhaps you missed a paragraph?

Answer (score 8):

> How do you deal with questions that fit this description?

Downvote and close them, with an explanation of course and a "[summer of love](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)" appropriate welcome comment. This will hopefully teach the asker that the type of question they've asked is not a good fit for StackOverflow and improve their behavior in the future.

You are not providing the user a service if you don't do this, in my opinion. Eventually they'll come across users who will take this action, so the sooner they are taught the *correct* type of question to ask and how to ask it, the more they will get out of the site, and the more valuable they will be to the community.

> Do you enjoy downvoting bad questions? I sort of do (but I make sure to explain why). Be honest.

I enjoy improving the quality of the site, whether that's through downvotes, closing questions, editing questions, or answering questions. So with that in mind, yes, I do enjoy downvoting bad questions because I hope it will ultimately improve the quality of StackOverflow.

> Since PHP seems to specifically exhibit this issue more than other topics, what are some objectively good PHP learners' aids; tutorials, practice guides, examples, etc?

Not sure because I'm not a PHP expert. But in the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tags we have similar issues with new users. I always direct them to MDN. I'm sure there's a similar resource for PHP out there.

Comment: @OP http://php.net contains pretty decent information for any user.

Comment: It's been claimed that the javascript and jquery tags do not suffer from this bias as much as PHP does.  I haven't checked this and I'm not going to until later, but why exactly is it that new PHP users tend to get singled out more often? perhaps there are simply more of them?

Comment: @Wug saying "I'm not sure if there's a bias yet, but why does the bias exist?" doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Wug seeing as it's presumably mostly fellow PHP users doing the downvoting and closing, I don't really see the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Almost everyday there is a new question posted about:

- a basic error with string concatenation
- a syntax error in a query because the data was not escaped

These questions already have lots of duplicates, and it is very easy to find the answer by just reading the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and [there](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Note: YES, I do know `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. But so many beginners use them that they should end up on the help page for `mysql_query` if only they did some simple research first.

So, my point is: I don't see a problem downvoting and closing very  basic questions whose answer is easily found just by reading the PHP manual!